# Two similar arrays produce falsity with == comparision?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, comparison, equals-operator

Lets take two arrays

```
var apple = [1,2,3];
var bracket = [1,2,3];
```

and a string cat here with the same contents as the initial 2 arrays with no difference except comma (,)

```
var cat = "1,2,3";
```

Now lets test the equality between the 2 arrays with the following code.

```
 if(apple == bracket){
        console.log("Both are equal");
    }
    else{
        console.log("Both are not equal");
 }
```

Everyone including me would have guessed it would print `Both are equal`.But the opposite is true.It prints `Both are not equal`.How is this possible.

Here is more surprice

```
if(apple == cat){
    console.log("Both are equal");
}
else{
    console.log("Both are not equal");
}
```

Here also the otherway the output comes,it would print `Both are equal`.

Comment: FYI, the reason your second comparison seemed to work is that when you compare a *string* with an *array*, the array is coerced to a string. When you coerce an array to a string, each of its elements is coerced to string and then they're joined up into one string with `,` in-between. So `[1, 2, 3] == "1,2,3"` is true because `String([1, 2, 3])` gives you `"1,2,3"`. Note that `[1, 2, 3] === "1,2,3"` would be false, because `===` doesn't do type coercion.

Comment: `==` where the operands are arrays doesn't check if the elements are the same, but if the reference (the object) is the same.

Comment: _If an object is compared with a number or string, JavaScript attempts to return the default value for the object. Operators attempt to convert the object to a primitive value, a String or Number value, using the valueOf and toString methods of the objects. If this attempt to convert the object fails, a runtime error is generated.[Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_Equality_Operators)_

Comment: The arrays might be *similar*, but they're not the *same*. The `==` equality operator checks for the latter on objects.